# 3ds Max get the type of the camera that is currently being used to render

Tags: c++, 3dsmax

I can't seem to figure out how to find the current camera type that is being rendered i.e. physical vs free vs targeted.

I have tried looking around in what GetCOREInterface returns as well as the 3ds max SDK documentation but nothing completely matches what I want.

```
GetCOREInterface()->GetActiveViewExp().GetViewCamera()
```

seems promising, but the camera in the active view may not be what's currently being rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering the question myself. Found out there is a method to get the current view that is being rendered. From there it is trivial to get the camera.

https://help.autodesk.com/view/3DSMAX/2017/ENU/?guid=__cpp_ref_class_interface16_html

```
GetCOREInterface16()->GetCurrentRenderView()->GetViewCamera()
```

From there you can get the cameras name or class_id.

Note this method only works on 3ds max 2016+. For pre 3ds max 2016 I recommend the method in my question which will work for most cases.